# prime number function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am new to Shell script. I have written a function to check weather a number is prime or not but I am getting error of Unary operator expected in if condition. Kindly point out where I have done mistake.

file :fprime.sh

```
 prime ()
 {

        n=$1
        t=0
        for i in {2..$n}
        do
        r=`expr $n % $i`
        if [ $r == 0 ]
        then
        t=`expr t + 1`
        fi
        done
        if [ $t == 1 ]
        then
        echo "prime"
        else
        echo "not prime"
        fi
 }

prime
```

Output:

```
~$ ./fprime.sh 5

expr: syntax error
./fprime.sh: line 8: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

not prime

Comment: Whenever you have a shell syntax error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing, 3 places there are other syntax error too,

```
1) if [ $r == 0 ]
   // to
   if [ $r -eq 0 ]

2) t=`expr t + 1`
   // to 
   t=`expr $t + 1`

3) if [ $t == 1 ]
   // to
   if [ $t -eq 1 ]
```

***Notes***

**1)** and **3)** , `-eq` is used to equate integers in bash `==` is to equate String/charactor(s)

**2)** - missed `$` symbol for variable `t`

Also, just to point out, you can directly use the `$1` without assigning to variable `n` again

Comment: I tried the changes suggested by you but still getting same error.
I am using ubuntu.

Comment: issue is solved. Thank you. Made following Changes:
for((i = 2; i < $1; i++));
  
do

r=$(($1 % i))

Comment: $n can't be used in braces and `expr` was not working in this case.

Comment: `$n can't be used in braces ` i didn't quite understood this,you can try this with `expr` and `$n` if you looking for this, `n=$(expr $n + 1)` or `n=$(expr ${n} + 1)`

Comment: I mean in for loop: for i in {1..$n}, $n can't  be used like this in for loop.

Comment: Yes, yes,, i missed that part .. there is no direct option for that, because variable expansion is happening after considering braces . there are two options, either you can go for `c` type `for` loop like you mentioned in above comment or you can make use of something like `eval` , for example `for i in $(eval echo {2..$n})` this will do your work.

Comment: There's no reason to use `expr` here at all; use an arithmetic expression `t=$((t + 1))` or an arithmetic statement `(( t+=1 ))` instead.

Comment: There is also no need to use `eval`; use a C-style `for` loop instead: `for ((i=2; i<=n; i++))`.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return 0 (no error --> true) if the number is prime.

The function will return 1 (error --> false) if the number is not prime.

For those who never saw it before, **REMAINDER_S** is an array (in which every reminder of the division, different from zero, is stored).

As prime numbers are divisible only by themselves (and 1 of course), in the moment a division provides a reminder equals to zero, the number will not be prime.

Otherwise (none of the reminders is zero), the array **REMINDER_S** will be empty and the number will be a prime number.

Do not forget to use "break" in the first "if" statement, if you intend to substitute the "return 1" for some echo message.

```
is_prime () {
    declare -a REMAINDER_S=()
    let ARG_1=$1-1
    for N in $(seq 2 $ARG_1)
    do
        let REMINDER=$1%$N
        if [ $REMINDER == 0 ]
        then
            REMINDER_S=("${REMINDER_S[@]}" $REMINDER)
            return 1
        fi      
    done

    if [ ${#REMINDER_S[@]} == 0 ]
    then
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple code :

```
function prime()
{
    for((i=2; i<=num; i++))
    do
        if [ `expr $num % $i` == 0 ]
        then
            echo $num is not prime
            exit
        fi
    done
    echo $num is a prime number
}

read num;
prime "$num";
```